# How do I bind AltGr+key to a symbol?

Tags: x11, keyboard-layout, xkb, xmodmap

I want to bind <kbd>AltGr</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd> to `æ`, and some other combinations, how can I do this? I also need <kbd>AltGr</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd> to `Æ`.

I normally use `setxkbmap` to change the keymap.

Comment: Why not use [Compose key](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compose_key) ?

Comment: @PM2Ring I need to type these characters often enough that compose key will get cumbersome, heck they have their own key on my native keyboard.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can accoplish that with custom XKB map. I recommend you to dump the current map with `xkbcomp $DISPLAY dump.xkb`, edit it and load it with `xkbcomp newmap.xkb $DISPLAY`. Dump file is pretty large and has a lot of superfluous information.

Easiest way to go about the editing is to look up how the altgr is used in your current map. It's usually ISO_LEVEL3 modifier. If your current keymap does not use altgr, you can try loading one that does to see how it can be done. For example `-layout us -variant altgr-intl` is pretty extensive and has most if not all european keys bound. Below is a short primer of what's going on.

xkb gets keycodes from kernel, sets a label for each and uses that label and modifier keys to decide what keysym it should output. Each key has a type assigned to it which defines what modifier keys it expects and what to output for each combination. Looking at the dump you got with `xkbcomp`: labels are defined in `xkb_keycodes`, types in `xkb_types` and label-to-keysym in `xkb_symbols`. Of these, `xkb_symbols` is the one you want to edit and reference the other two to know what to change. You can also just look at the `xkb_symbols` and find how it's currently done and edit as appropriate.

`xkb_types` section holds different modifier levels for key definitions and you'll want to one which has altgr and shift modes. Example:

```
type "FOUR_LEVEL_ALPHABETIC" {
    modifiers= Shift+Lock+LevelThree;
    map[Shift]= Level2;
    map[Lock]= Level2;
    map[LevelThree]= Level3;
    map[Shift+LevelThree]= Level4;
    map[Lock+LevelThree]= Level4;
    map[Shift+Lock+LevelThree]= Level3;
    level_name[Level1]= "Base";
    level_name[Level2]= "Shift";
    level_name[Level3]= "Alt Base";
    level_name[Level4]= "Shift Alt";
};
```

That means that key marked as `FOUR_LEVEL_ALPHABETIC` has four modes. Normal, shift/caps, altgr, altgr-shift which sounds like what you're looking for.

Now you want to find out what the keycode for w is if you don't know it already. 
`xev | grep -A2 --line-buffered '^KeyRelease' | sed -n '/keycode /s/^.*keycode \([0-9]*\).* (.*, \(.*\)).*$/\1 \2/p'` gives you the keycode for keys you press. `grep` is there to make the output more readable.

Cross-reference the keycode you got with `xkb_keycodes` section of the dump map you got earlier. For me, w gives keycode 25. `less` the dump and find the correct keycode in form of `<LABEL> = ##;`, example `<AD02> = 25;`. Or `cat dump.xkb| grep ' = 25;'` Label is just a name xkb uses to reference the key in later sections.

Now that you have the label, go to `xkb_symbols` which actually maps the labels to keysyms. The format is

```
key <AD02> {
        type= "FOUR_LEVEL_ALPHABETIC",
        symbols[Group1]= [  w, W, aring, Aring ]
    };
```

`type=` is the type you want from `xkb_types` section, `symbols[Group1]=` has one keysym for each of the modes required by the type. Again, normal, shift/caps, altgr, shift-altgr for this type. `[Group1]`, as far as I've understood is a method of using multiple keymaps you can change on the fly with a lock key you set up. I don't use groups myself so everything is group1 for me.

to find all the different keysyms you can use here, check `/usr/include/X11/keysymdef.h`. The two symbols you're looking for are `ae` for æ and `AE` for Æ.

```
key <AD02> {
        type= "FOUR_LEVEL_ALPHABETIC",
        symbols[Group1]= [  w, W, ae, AE ]
    };
```

I may have rambled a bit. Check out [Arch Wiki's](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/X_KeyBoard_extension) page on XKB, it's good stuff no matter what OS or distro you're using.

Answer (score 5):

This is easy to do with [`xmodmap`](http://www.x.org/archive/current/doc/man/man1/xmodmap.1.xhtml). You can use a `keysym` directive to change the keysyms associated with a key. This affect all the keys that are currently sending this keysym with any modifier combination. For normal printable characters, the four keysyms are the ones for the bare key, the key with <kbd>Shift</kbd>, the key with <kbd>AltGr</kbd> and the key with <kbd>AltGr</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd> respectively.

```
keysym A = a A aring Aring
keysym O = o O oslash Ooblique
keysym W = w W ae AE
```

Put these directives in a file, e.g. `~/.Xmodmap`, and load them with `xmodmap ~/.Xmodmap`. The file called `~/.Xmodmap` is automatically loaded when you log in in some environments (this depends on your unix variant and desktop environment).

You can find keysym names in `/usr/share/X11/locale/en_US.UTF-8/Compose` or `/usr/include/X11/keysymdef.h` (Debian locations, may vary on other systems). If you don't know the keysym name for a symbol, you can use its Unicode number: `U` followed by hexadecimal digits, e.g.

```
keysym W = w W U00e6 U00c6
```

Answer (score 2):

In your symbol `(/usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/XY`) file, under your keyboard variant find the line `{ [         w,          W,`. These two, obviously, correspond to lower- and upper-case w. Now after them the third and fourth entries correspond to what you get when you press <kbd>AltGr</kbd> 
+<kbd>w</kbd> and <kbd>AltGr</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>w</kbd> respectively.

You should just replace those third and fourth characters with your desired ones or if they're absent, add them.

According to Wikipedia their (ae, AE) unicode points are U+00E6 and U+00C6 respectively so your new, edited line of your symbol file should be (omiting the + sign)

```
{ [         w,          W,   U00E6,   U00C6 ]   };
```

A system update updating this file overwrites it, so you'd better keep a copy of this edited file somewhere in your home and whenever it's overwritten by an update replace it with the command

```
sudo cp /YOUR/BACKUP/SYMBOL_FILE /usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/SYMBOL_FILE
```